# Java: añadir un valor sin sobreescribirlo

Tags: java, hashmap

Tengo un hashmap<String,Integer> llamado "dinero del usuario", con la opción .put le puedo poner dinero al usuario pero si en otro momento vuelvo a usar .put, sobreescribo el dinero que ya tenía,  y no quiero eso

```
//.put(user,10) 
//.put(user,15)
//deberia ser 25 en total, pero sobreescribe el dinero y se queda en 15 y no quiero eso

private void ponerDinero(String user, int moneyQuantity) {
    userMoney.put(user, moneyQuantity);
}

private void añadirDinero(Member user, int moneyQuantity) {
    userMoney.add(user,moneyQuantity); // Esto no existe!
}
```

Comment: obten el valor que tiene actualmente, Luego sumas los valores por código y haces el put con el valor actualizado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar el método [`merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) de los `Map`s en java. El método `merge` agrega la clave y el valor si aún no existe en el `Map`, o combina los valores en una sola clave mediante una función si los valores existen. Este método recibe tres parámetros:

1. La clave del `Map` (en tu caso el usuario).
2. El valor (en tu caso la cantidad de dinero).
3. Una función "combinadora" que combinará los valores en caso de existir dos claves repetidas. Como lo que se quiere es sumar la cantidad ingresada, esta función sería la suma de dos enteros (`Integer::sum`).

Teniendo en cuenta esto tu método quedaría:

```java
private void ponerDinero(String user, int moneyQuantity) {
    userMoney.merge( user, moneyQuantity, Integer::sum );
}
```